# Am I doing correct when I want to get a random uint in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to get a random uint in C#, am I doing correctly?

```
Random ran;
a[i] = (uint)ran.Next(int.MaxValue); //random only gets to maxInt
if (ran.Next(2) == 1)
    a[i] = (uint)(a[i] | (1 << 31));
```

Another thing that confuses me is that I can't write it as `(uint)(a[i] | (uint)(1 << 31))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you even try running your code? It should throw `NullReferenceException` right away, because you don't initialize your `ran` random generator.

And you can simply get random int from within `int.MinValue` and `int.MaxValue` and cast it to `uint` <strike>in `unchecked` context:</strike>

```
Random ran = new Random();
a[i] = (uint)ran.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
```

Comment: You should be using the overload of `Random.Next` that takes no parameters, unless you're explicitly trying here to exclude `int.MaxValue` as a possible result. It's an *exclusive* upper bound when using the overloads that take parameters.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The one without parameters returns only positive numbers, so it would not be enough to fill `uint`.

Comment: I've now posted an alternative that can return all possible `uint` values.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a random `uint` for the entire possible range, we shouldn't be using [`Random.Next(int,int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) because the second parameter is an exclusive upper bound.

(i.e. it will never generate the binary value 01111111111111111111111111111111).

I thought [`Random.Next()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b3ta19y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be suitable, but as  **MarcinJuraszek** points out, that doesn't produce half the range required.

So if you do want the full range of possible results, I guess it's time for:

```
var ran = new Random();
var buffer = new byte[4];
ran.GetBytes(buffer);
a[i] = BitConverter.ToUint32(buffer,0);
```